# How to get ad images from an advertising account using the Facebook API

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Good morning to all.

Recently I was working on the **Facebook API** trying to extract the images of the ads from an advertising account. The problem I have is to use creative to get the **image_url** field I realize that **only some ads** in my account return the image_url, that is, I can't get all the images as I want.

I also tried with **thumbnail_url** but it returns me images clipped in miniature, you can modify its dimensions with *thumbnail_height* and *thumbnail_width* but all it does is enlarge the image in pixels but the cropping of them continues.

My response request to the Facebook API is this:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/act_131251207293544?fields=ads{id,name,creative{image_url,status}}
```

I don't know if any of you know another way to extract these ad images so that **all the ads** have their corresponding image at the time of consulting the API and this displayed in its **original size**.

I thank you very much for your collaboration

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know if any of you know another way to extract these ad images
>   so that all the ads have their corresponding image at the time of
>   consulting the API and this displayed in its original size.

I worked with Facebook SDK for years, and I developed a similar feature like that.

First of all, read all the ad creativities of your account[[doc]](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/ad-units):

```
curl -G \
  -d 'fields=name' \
  -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adcreatives
```

Then, read the detail of every creative [[doc]](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative):

```
curl -G \
  -d 'fields=name,object_story_id' \
  -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/<CREATIVE_ID>
```

Then read the detail of `object_story_spec`. As far as I see, the image and video URLs are in `object_story_spec`. Here is the field of `object_story_spec` [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative-object-story-spec/):

[image]

The data you want should in `photo_data`.

But be aware! The `object_story_spec` varies from the type of ad, 
so you should do it very carefully.

For example, if it's a video ad or text ad, there may be no `photo_data` at all.

If you have any questions, please no hesitate to leave a comment here.

Comment: I've noticed that some ads will come through with only a thumbnail_url and no object_story_spec even though they are a carousel or video type ad. Checking the ad preview however /{adcreativeId OR adId}/previews?ad_format=DESKTOP_FEED_STANDARD clearly shows the ad does indeed feature multiple high quality images, however they are nowhere to be seen in the ad properties. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can nest the graph call to get the creative content fields like this: https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/act_YOURNUMBER/ads?fields=id,name,adset {id,name},campaign {id,name},creative{id, title, object_story_spec{photo_data, text_data, video_data, link_data, template_data}}

Comment: @DavidJones is correct, object_story_spec is only available for ads with dynamic content active. (Correct me if im wrong)

Answer (score 1):

@Sayakiss answers is partially correct.

***If I understand well :***

In some cases when Dynamic content is not active on Facebook Ads the relation is  one image for one ad. (1 to 1)

Look at this request,

```
act_***************/ads?fields=name,insights{clicks},creative{name}&filtering=[{field: "id" , operator : "EQUAL", value: "*****" }]
```

You can get both image and metrics about the Ad on the same request

The Id in the filter is the Ad Id